# Typescript type inference not recognizing value must be defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

This might not be possible in typescript but it seems like the TS compiler should be able to figure this out some way. Example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDBmFcDsGMBcEsD2kAEA3AhgG3gEw7AKYBiiiAFJlgFwoDOsATvJAOYoA%20KUuhoLhXAEoUAb2ApJKRoVjhGqKigCEAXlXdIvfpEEoA-CibhCKWqGx1CwAL4gsslAFsAngDVstBszadN2gVwQeFAUSmw8AhIyclcPLCERcSkUaGQ6RAcAOixEVnIAIkRwWAAHEtoCgBpnd2ws2EQAGUQAd0JGAGEMK3JE2yA)

```
function validateFoo(val: string | undefined) {
    return val !== undefined ? true : false
}

let myVal: string | undefined

if (validateFoo(myVal)) {
    console.log("output: ", myVal.toLowerCase()) // Error: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
}
```

it *seems* like inside the `if` statement that myVal **must** not be undefined. However typescript says it may be. Is there some way to annotate that function similar maybe to:

```
if (!myVal) {
  throw new Error("myVal undefined")
}

console.log(myVal.toLowerCase())
```

would mark `myVal` as defined after the throw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what type guards does:

```
function validateFoo(val: string | undefined): val is string {
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

Comment: [Strikes again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404944/is-there-a-canonical-question-for-user-defined-type-guards-in-typescript?cb=1)

Comment: Thanks for this - i didn't really know how to phrase the question to search the docs

Comment: @JaredSmith or @Federkun to avoid another duplicate question - using guard makes the type `never` in the `else` is there a way to annotate that? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDBmFcDsGMBcEsD2kAEA3AhgG3gEw7AKYBiiiAFJlgFwoCyAngCoMAOhKAPilLoaPEiFcASlpUU8AM71mbDgG9gKFSgBOhWODWoqAfgB0iVgmTYW7FAEIAvDZ6Q+AobhR6UsNeA61Q2KYTAAL4gsPKyFhz2SqqSuLRSnoIA5sqqxqaQ5vJ6CUmQqSHAWJooALYMAGrYtIyRXA5OgsIg8KAolNh4BCRk5BXVWCIiKDGq0MhSiCUGWIjJ5ABEiOCwrKu0iwA05VXYBngGsIgAMogA7oRqAMIYAeTDwSiEWAGjaSoA9J8oAFbgiRQACNCNAMACOFRukR1JptC4UH5XhxcIhCFJIAByWDlDAAaw4A2wKCEaCuHxQE0gUxmcwWy1W61gmx2RKwhkOxzOlxud0IDxEwSAA